# Equivalent conditions of prime ideals in Lie algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-explanation, lie-algebras, maximal-and-prime-ideals

I am studding on Lie algebra and prime ideals, but some problems rise up to me.
please look on this and try to help me.

Definition: An ideal $P$ of $L$ is called prime if $[H, K] \subseteq P$ with $H, K$ ideals of $L$ implies $H \subseteq P$ or $K \subseteq P$.

THEOREM : Let $P$ it be an ideal of L. Then the following conditions are equivatent}:

i) $P$ is prime.

ii) If $[a, H]\subseteq P$ for $a \in L$ and an ideal $H$ of $L$, then either $a\in P$ or $H\subseteq P.$

iii) If $[a, <b^{L}>]\subseteq P$ for $a, b\in L$, then either $a\in P$ or $b\in P.$

PROOF. 
$\mathrm{i}$)
$\Rightarrow \mathrm{i}\mathrm{i}\mathrm{i}$). For each $a\in L,$

$$
<a^{L}>=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} V_{i},
$$
where $V_{0}=(a)$ and $V_{i} [(a),\underline{{L],\ldots,}_{i-times}}L]$. If $[a,\ <b^{L}>]\subseteq P$, we assert that
$$
$$
$[V_{i},\ <b^{L}>]\subseteq P$ for all $i\geq 0$. In fact, it is true for $i=0$. Let $i\geq 1$ and assume that the assertion is true for $i-1$. Then
$$
[V_{i},\ <b^{L}>]=[[V_{i-}{}_{1}L],\ <b^{L}>]
$$
$$
\subseteq[[V_{i-1},\ <b^{L}>],\ L]+[V_{i-1},\ [L,\ <b^{L}>]]
$$
$$
\subseteq[P,\ L]+[V_{i-1},\ <b^{L}>]\subseteq P_{:}
$$
Thus we have the assertion.

> It follows that
>   $$
> [<a^{L}>,<b^{L}>]\subseteq P.
> $$
>   Since $P$ is prime, either $<a^{L}>\subseteq P$ or $<b^{L}>\subseteq P$ and so $a\in P$ or $b\in P.$

$\mathrm{i}\mathrm{i}\mathrm{i})\Rightarrow \mathrm{i}\mathrm{i})$ . Let $a\in L\backslash P$ and let $H$ be an ideal of $L$ such that $[a,\ H]\subseteq P$. For any $b\in H, [a,\ <b^{L}>]\subseteq P$ since the ideal $<b^{L}>$ is contained in  $H$. As $a\not\in P,$ iii) implies $b\in P$. Hence $H\subseteq P.$

> $\mathrm{i}\mathrm{i})\Rightarrow \mathrm{i})$ . Let $H, K$ be ideals of $L$ such that $[H,\ K]\subseteq P$ and $H\not\subset P$. Since $[a,\ K]\subseteq P$ for any $a\in H\backslash P$, we have $K\subseteq P$ by ii). Therefore $P$ is prime.

My questions( I need more explanation about this points which have color) :-

1) It follows that $[<a^{L}>,<b^{L}>]\subseteq P.$ (why this true) ??

2) Since $P$ is prime, either $<a^{L}>\subseteq P$ or $<b^{L}>\subseteq P$ and so $a\in P$ or $b\in P.$ (why this true) ??

3) Since $[a,\ K]\subseteq P$ for any $a\in H\backslash P$ (why this true) ??

Comment: "Lie algebra" after Sophus Lie, not "lie algebra".

Comment: Use \langle and \rangle to make it look like $\langle b^L \rangle$ instead of $<b^L>$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source is Naoki Kawamoto, [On Prime Ideals of Lie Algebras](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.hmj/1206136843) (Hiroshima Math J. **4** (1974), 679--684), Theorem 1.

To quote the paper and to correct your typesetting: $$\langle a^L \rangle = \sum_{i=0}^\infty V_i \qquad \text{where} \qquad V_0 = (a) \qquad \text{and} \qquad V_i = [\ldots[(a),\underbrace{L],\ldots,}_i\ L]. \tag{1}$$

That is, $V_1 = [(a),L], \quad V_2 = [[(a),L],L], \quad V_3=[[[(a),L],L],L],\quad$ etc.

1) To show $[\langle a^L \rangle,\langle b^L \rangle] \subseteq P$ it suffices to show $[V_i, \langle b^L \rangle] \subseteq P$ for each $i \geqslant 0$. This sufficiency follows from $(1)$. Showing $[V_i, \langle b^L \rangle] \subseteq P$ is what is done in the proof. To summarize the argument: the case $i=0$ is true by assumption, and the rest follows by induction and the Jacobi identity.

2) Since $P$ is prime, either $\langle a^L\rangle \subseteq P$ or $\langle b^L \rangle \subseteq P$ (this is the definition of prime). If $\langle a^L \rangle \subseteq P$ then we have $a \in \langle a^L \rangle \subseteq P$, so $a \in P$. In the same way, if $\langle b^L \rangle \subseteq P$ then $b \in P$. So $a \in P$ or $b \in P$.

3) $[a,K] \subseteq P$ for any $a \in H\setminus P$ is true by the first assumption on $H$ and $K$ made in the preceding sentence, that is $[H,K] \subseteq P$. Indeed, for $a \in H\setminus P$ we have $a\in H$ and hence $[a,K] \subseteq [H,K] \subseteq P$.

---

To answer the questions in the comment:

4. > What is the meaning of $(a)$?

   $L$ is a Lie algebra over a field $\Phi$. For any element $a$ of $L$, $\langle a^L \rangle$ is defined to be the smallest ideal of $L$ containing $a$. An ideal $I$ is a $\Phi$-vector subspace of $L$ satisfying $[I,L] \subset L$. So what is $\langle a^L \rangle$ as a $\Phi$-vector space? Of course it must contain $a$, and all its scalar multiples, i.e. the $1$-dimensional $\Phi$-vector subspace $(a) := \Phi a \subset \langle a^L \rangle$. But if it contains $(a)$, then (by definition of ideal) it must also contain $[(a),L]$, and hence $[[(a),L],L]$, etc. Because it is a $\Phi$-vector space it must contain their sum. This leads to $(1)$.
5. > How you use the Jacobi identity in the first one?

   It is used to go from line 1 to line 2 in the display equation: $[[V_{i-1},L], \langle b^L \rangle]$ is a set consisting of $[[x,y],z]$ such that $x \in V_{i-1}, y \in L, z \in \langle b^L \rangle$. By the Jacobi identity $(I)$ and antisymmetry $(II)$ we have:
   $$\begin{align*}[[x,y],z] &= -[[y,z],x] -[[z,x],y] \tag{I} \\
   & = [[x,z],y] + [x,[y,z]] \tag{II} \\ &\in [[V_{i-1},\langle b^L \rangle],L] + [V_{i-1},[L,\langle b^L \rangle]].\end{align*}$$
   Hence $[[V_{i-1},L], \langle b^L \rangle] \subseteq [[V_{i-1},\langle b^L \rangle],L] + [V_{i-1},[L,\langle b^L \rangle]]$.
6. > How can we prove that if $\langle b^L \rangle$ is contained in $H$ then $[a,\langle b^L \rangle] \subseteq [a,H]$?

   This is by definition, or the meaning of the notation: $[a,\langle b^L \rangle]$ is a set consisting of $[a,y]$ with $y \in \langle b^L \rangle$ and $[a,H]$ is a set consisting of $[a,z]$ with $z \in H$. Since $y \in \langle b^L \rangle \subseteq H$, we have $y \in H$, so $[a,y] \in [a,H]$, hence $[a,\langle b^L \rangle] \subseteq [a,H]$
7. > How can we prove that if $a \in H$ then $[a,K] \subseteq [H,K]$?

   Same/similar reason: $[H,K]$ is a set consisting of $[x,y]$ with $x \in H$ and $y \in K$, and $[a,K]$ is a set consisting of $[a,z]$ with $z \in K$. Since $a \in H$, we have $[a,z] \in [H,K]$, so $[a,K] \subseteq [H,K]$.

Comment: What is the meaning of $(a)$ ?\\

How you use the Jacobi identity in the first one?\\

How can we prove that if $<b^L> $is contained in $H$ then $[a,b^{L}>] \subseteq [a,H>]$?\\

How can we prove that if $a \in H$ then $[a,K] \subseteq [H,K]$?\\

Comment: Can I prove that  if $a^n \in H$ then$ [a,K] \subseteq [H,K]  $ ?
 where n is non negative integer

Comment: What do you mean by $a^n$ if $a$ is an element of a Lie algebra?

Comment: what it may be mean ? I dont know exactly

Comment: Do you mean that no element with this form in Lie algebra ??

Comment: I'm asking what you mean by that notation, because in a Lie algebra you only have a bracket. Does $a^2$ mean $[a,a] = -[a,a] = 0$?

Comment: 1-So, Does every $a^n$ is equal to zero ?
2- If $H$ is an ideal  in Lie Algebra, Does there are  $H^n$ in Lie algebra?

Comment: 1. However you want to define $a^n$, for $n \geqslant 2$ it will probably be zero, yes. 2. $H^2 = [H,H]$ means the set of $[x,y]$ for $x \in H$ and $y \in H$. By contrast to the square of a single element, this $H^2$ may be nonzero, because it may contain $[x,y] \neq 0$ (in which case necessarily $x \neq y$). For higher exponents see the [lower central series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1221163/determining-the-derived-series-and-the-lower-central-series-of-a-lie-algebra) and for exponents in parentheses see the derived series (on the same page).